# Work and Time related problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A and B do a work together in 16 days. B and C can do the same work together in 20 days. How many days will it take for A, B and C to do the work together?

Comment: Tip: I'd say use a a venn diagram to get you started. Using some set notation will definitely help as well.

Comment: More than 8.8 days...

Comment: how did you solve it? @Tunococ

Comment: @rahul I wouldn't say I solved it. That was just a lower bound of the set of possible answers. (To be precise, I meant $80/9$.) The problem doesn't give enough information to find a unique solution. By the way, it would help to let others know what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried the usual approaches to solve this kind of problems, like finding out what portion of the work they can do in a single day (combined and individually), but I also think the data is insufficient to find an unique solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B,C$ represent their daily efficiencies in percentage, and the total amount of work to be $1$(think about $100\%$).

Then you have 
$$16(A+B)=1\quad\text{and}\quad20(B+C)=1.$$

To solve exactly the amount of days by A,B,C working together, you need to know how many days will be taken by A and C working together.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I faced the same hurdle, but was not sure if the data was insufficient or not. That's why I asked it here.

Comment: @rahul You have more variables than equations, it cannot be solved in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

$A+B=16$ in $1$ day $A+B$ finishes  $1/16$ part of the work
$B+C=20$  in $1$ day $B+C$ finishes $1/20$ part of the work
therefore $A+B+C$  all together can finish the work in $1/16 + 1/20 =1/9$
ans is $9$ days

Comment: Wrong.When you add them,you should get A+2B+C.

Comment: Could you now please delete this answer?